# batch file to create and write to VBScript file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am creating a batch script that creates and writes to a VBScript. I am writing to the file like this:

```
echo (code for vbscript) >> [name of vbscript].vbs
```

However, there is one part of the code that is troubling me:

```
echo If Len(m) > 1 then >> sys.vbs
```

Since the code itself has a `>` symbol in it, the batch file interprets it as me trying to write to the VBScript and cuts off the code, but that is not the case. I want the code to say `If Len(m) > 1 Then` but instead it just says `If Len(m)  then`.

I already tried working around this by modifying the code to say:

```
echo if NOT Len(m) < 1 then >> sys.vbs
```

but that does not work either. If I do that, then it omits the whole line of code altogether.

I'm sorry if I didn't explain this problem well enough, it's hard to describe.

Comment: Escape the `>` with a caret.  Depending on whether this `echo` statement lives within a parenthetical, you might also need to escape the parentheses.  `echo if Len^(m^) ^> 1 then >> sys.vbs`

Comment: Writing a BAT script that writes a VBScript sounds like an awfully roundabout way of doing something. Are you really sure this is necessary? Are you really sure that doing it *this way* is necessary? I have a hard time imagining a problem that would make this approach the best option. Maybe your time is better spent thinking about a better approach than about these kinds of clumsy workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

`<`, `>` and `>>` are [redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) in batch. As [@rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40825688/batch-file-to-create-and-write-to-vbscript-file#comment68869799_40825688) already pointed out in the comments you need to escape them with a caret (`^`) if you want to echo them as literal characters in the output file:

```
echo If Len(m) ^> 1 Then >> sys.vbs
```

Using double quotes around the echoed string does not work in this case, because `echo` includes the double quotes in the output.

However, I agree with [@Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40825688/batch-file-to-create-and-write-to-vbscript-file#comment68875782_40825688) that you may want to reconsider your approach. Generating VBScript from a batch file on the fly is usually not a good/clean way of solving whatever problem you have on your hands.